# Can't understand the logic of POST request with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, post, android-annotations

I want to use AndroidAnnotations to send POST request. In my POST request I need to send two String parameters - Mail and Phone.

I am trying to do this with following code.
Here is the definition of POST method:

```
@Post("&Action=login")
LoginWebInfo getLoginWebInfo (TreeMap data);
```

And here is how I call this method:

```
TreeMap<String, String> data = new TreeMap<String, String>();
data.put("Mail", email);
data.put("Phone", phone);
return webInteractionWithUserClient.getRegistrationWebInfo(data);
```

But this code doesn't seem to work. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

use a multivalue map not a tree

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

data.add("mail",email);
data.add("Phone", phone);

LoginWebInfo logWebInfo = webInteractionWithUserClient.getRegistrationWebInfo(data);
```